# BeautifulSoup: How to add script src attribute with querystring without encoding the url?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to add a new script tag that has query parameters to my html document so I tried this:

```
jsmanager = self.soup.new_tag("script", src="https://example.com/myscript.js?data=test&alarm=1")
self.soup.select_one("head").append(jsmanager)
```

The problem is that after the script element is added the url in the src attribute looks like this:

```
https://example.com/myscript.js?data=test&amp;alarm=1
```

Is there any way to add src attribute without html-encoding it's value? (The & thing).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not actually a problem - this is valid html. Both `jsmanager.get('src')` and `jsmanager.attrs['src']` will give the same link as you set, and `jsmanager.prettify(formatter=None)` will also show the tag without encoding the ampersand [the '&' character].

If you add to a html

```
<script src="https://example.com/myscript.js?data=test&amp;alarm=1"></script>
```

it should behave as intended. In fact, if you render

```
<a href="https://example.com/myscript.js?data=test&amp;alarm=1"></a>
```

and right-click on the link and then *Copy link address* you will be able to paste the link with the original `&` instead of `&amp;`.

Comment: Ok, got it, thank you. But is it possible to add querystring to a link without encoding? Or it can't be done anyway.

Comment: @DanielVygolov [just to be clear, the actual link's querystring - as in what gets entered in the address bar of a browser - should have `&` not `&amp;`.] If you're writing your own html manually and you add without encoding, it will still work, but bs4 is more "strict" with itself, so it will always automatically encode [and afaik there's no way to override that]